# Algorithm for player to always see things a certain way in 3 player game

Tags: c++, algorithm

Say I have a table that fits 4 players: 
But only 3 players are used in this gane: A, B, C.

on the server, the layout is like this:

```
    C
B
    A
```

But all players must see it both with the correct player order, ex: ABC, BCA, CAB
and they must also think that no one is sitting in the top, north position, the client always thinks the bottom and 2 sides are occupied.

So for example:
The server sees the above, but C sees:

```
A       B
    C
```

B sees:

```
 C      A
     B
```

and A sees:

```
B      C
    A
```

I'm trying to figure out an algorithm that can figure out, given the position on the server, which position this maps too on the client. For example, if I tell it I want to see which position on client B does the server's A map too? The answer would be, index 1 on the server maps to index 3 on the client. I'd also like to do the inverse.

I'd program it manually but I'm wondering if an algorithm could do this since there is a pattern.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have 4 players in a ring configuration, then store the player locations in an array on the server, and map them to the display locations on each client.

Example:

Absolute positions: `position=[A, B, C]`

User A sees: A in the center, index `0`. B to the right, index `0 + 1`, C to the left, index `0 - 1 MOD 3`

User B sees: B in the center, index `1`. C to the right, index `1 + 1`. A to the left, index `1 - 1`.

User C sees: C in the center, index `2`. A to the right, index `2 + 1 MOD 3`. B to the left, index `2 - 1`.

Comment: You're going counter clockwise but this helps.

Comment: I haven't got it figured out.

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure I understood your question, because it looks trivial, but..

it's just a circular shift.

```
pos = (pos - mypos) % numofplayers
```

Comment: Not quite, this does not consider that clients skip the north portion and only see players on east west and south.

Comment: 3 players, 3 positions. forget about north.

Comment: What I mean is, for certain players, certain things would map to North, in those cases the position is increased or decreased by 1 to ensure that the client never receives a north position.

Comment: Seems like you should define static mappings for each player.